# Imported module value undefined with jest when used in multiple files

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an issue where importing default export module in nested components returns undefined.
I have created function for creating API service redux objects, basically a simple object mapping where i pass in service routes and map them to reducers etc.

```
export default services = (routes) => {
 const _temp = {};
 Object.keys(routes).forEach(route => {
  _temp[route] = createReducer(route);
 });
 return _temp;
}
```

Routes is hard coded object { [key: string]: string }, so this function should never return undefined. I use same function for redux combineReducers and it works there with jest. Logging out store inside test has all these values, same as logging out services will return object.

However, if i have a component that also imports and uses services for dispatch, i will get error that services[route] is undefined. So component and store setup both use `import services from 'module';`

Component looks something like this:

```
<ComponentUsedForTest>
 <ComponentThatUsesImport />
 <div>Whatever jsx</div>
</ComponentUsedForTest>
```

And test render:

```
test('Component test', () => {
 render(<ComponentUsedForTest/>);
 // Error cannot read services[route] of undefined on store setup. 
 // Won't happen and everything works fine if component does not use services import, services object is not undefined.
}
```

I have tried following:

1. Mock this module using jest.mock and jest.requireActual.
2. Import using import * as services from 'module'
3. Remove default export and use named export

From my understanding this could be a problem of using same module import in multiple places so after first import jest overrides initial value as undefined for same import. But if this is the case i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I don't have concrete solutions for this.

Comment: I bypassed this issue by removing module import that i used for dispatch in component and called rest api directly. I was planning on removing redux anyway in favor of custom state machine, but hoped i wouldn't have to do it so soon.